# When do tamely ramified Belyi maps exist in characteristic p?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, belyi

Let $p$ be a prime. Let $d$ be a number. Let $\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_{\infty}$ be three partitions of $d$ whose parts are prime to $p$. Consider the following question:

> Does there exist a finite cover $C \to \mathbb P^1_{\overline{\mathbb F}_p} $ that is unramified away from $0$, $1$, and $\infty$, with ramification degrees given by the partition $\lambda_0$ at $0$, $\lambda_1$ at $1$, and $\lambda_{\infty}$ at $\infty$?

In characteristic $0$, I understand completely how to answer this question. It is exactly when there are permutations $\sigma_0, \sigma_1,\sigma_\infty \in S_d$ of cycle types $\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_{\infty}$ satisfying $\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_\infty=1$. (and generating a subgroup acting transitively on the $d$ letters, if we want the cover to be connected) Checking for that existence is group theory or combinatorics.

In characteristic $p$ I only know incredibly partial answers to this question - specifically, I know that if there are three such permutations and they generate a group of order prime to $p$, then there is a cover. I also believe I know that if there is not a cover in characteristic $0$ with some partitions, there is not one in characteristic $p$ either.

> What are other sufficient conditions on $\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_{\infty}$ for $C$ to exist? What are other necessary conditions?
>
> Are there arguments that certain cases must be very difficult, and no answer could be forthcoming? Which cases are problematic?

Comment: Some typos: "... be three partitions"; "if there is not a cover in characteristic 0 with some partitions, there is not one in characteristic $p$ either."

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot of work done about this by people such as Raynaud, Harbater, Stevenson, Bouw, Wewers, Osserman and others (please edit here if you want to add more). An example result very close to what you are looking for is Theorem 1.4 of the paper [Linear series and existence of branched covers](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=1689540) by Brian Osserman. You can also find the paper [on the arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.AG/0507096).

Comment: Osserman's result gives necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a genus-$0$ curve $C$ with $C\to\mathbf{P}^1$ having prescribed ramification.  So this answers the stated questions in case the $\lambda_i$ have a combined total of $d+2$ parts.